# Baixar arquivo como zip com PHP

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte arquivo vindo do banco de dados:

```
$sqlAnexos = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM arquivos");

while($jmArquivos = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlAnexos)){

...
echo "<a href='download.php?key=".$jmArquivos->IdCodArquivos."'>".$jmArquivos->Arquivos."</a>";
...
}
```

Gostaria que ao clicar no link dos arquivos, fosse feito o download como zip. Tentei com o código abaixo, mas não funcionou:

**Página downloads.php**

```
<?php
 $sqlArquivos = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM arquivos WHERE IdCodArquivos = '".$_REQUEST["key"]."';");
 $jmArquivos = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlArquivos);


    $zipar = new ZipArchive();
    $arquivo = $jmArquivos->Arquivos;
    if($zipar->open('nome_arquivo_zip.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) == TRUE){
       $zipar->addFile($arquivo,$arquivo);
    }else{
      echo "Erro";
    }
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($arquivo));
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($arquivo).".zip");
    readfile($arquivo.".zip");
    $zipar->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: Ué, você gera um zip mas serve o arquivo original... E acho que deveria fechar o zip antes de servir.

Comment: Olá bfavaretto. Ele chega a gerar o zip, mas dá erro ao descompactar.

Answer (score 1):

Eu tive problemas semelhantes para arquivos ZIP grandes
E resolvi da seguinte forma:

No seu php.ini, faça:

- Upload_max_filesize - 1500 M
- Max_input_time - 1000
- Memory_limit - 640M
- Max_execution_time - 1800
- Post_max_size - 2000 M

No seu arquivo php de donwload, faça:

```
$filename = "MyFile.zip";     //nome do seu arquivo      
$filepath='../downloads/'.$filename;    //a pasta onde está o arquivo   
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 200 OK');
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");    
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath)); 
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=\"".basename($filepath)."\"");


while (ob_get_level()) 
{
 ob_end_clean();
 }
readfile($filepath);   
exit;
ob_start ();
```